# pandas.plot argument c vs s

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code from a machine learning book in python:

```
copy_set.plot(kind = "scatter" , x = "longitude" , 
              y = "latitude" , alpha = 0.4 , 
              s = copy_set[ "population" ], 
              label = "population" , figsize=(10,7), 
              c = "median_house_value" , cmap = plt.get_cmap ( "jet" ) )
```

`median_house_value` and `population` are two columns in the `copy_set` dataframe. I don't understand why for argument `s` I have to use `copy_set['population']` but for argument `c` it is possible to only use the column name `median_house_value`. When I try to only use the column name for parameter `s`, I get an an error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: What is the output from `copy_set.info()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very good question. `df.plot` is a wrapper around several of matplotlib's plotting functions. For `kind="scatter"` matplotlib's `scatter` function will be called. Most of the arguments to `df.plot()` are first converted to the data within the `Series` you get from the dataframe's column of the respective name.

E.g.

```
df.plot(x="lon", y="lat")
```

will be converted to

```
ax.scatter(x=df["lon"].values, y=df["lat"].values)
```

Remaining arguments are passed through to scatter,
hence

```
df.plot(x="lon", y="lat", some_argument_pandas_doesnt_know=True)
```

will result in

```
ax.scatter(x=df["lon"].values, y=df["lat"].values, some_argument_pandas_doesnt_know=True)
```

So while pandas converts th arguments `x`, `y`, `c`, it doesn't do so for `s`. `s` is hence simply passed on to `ax.scatter`, but that matplotlib function doesn't know what some string like `"population"` would mean.
For arguments that are passed on to the matplotlib function one would need to stick to matplotlib's signature and in the case of `s` supply the data directly.

Note however, that matplotlib's scatter itself also allows to use strings for its arguments. This however requires to tell it from which dataset they shall be taken. This is done via the `data` argument. Hence the following works fine and would be the matplotlib equivalent to the pandas call in the question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2), columns=["lon", "lat"])
df["pop"] = np.random.randint(5,300,size=20)
df["med"] = np.random.rand(20)*1e5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
sc = ax.scatter(x = "lon", y = "lat", alpha = 0.4, 
                s = "pop", label = "population" , 
                c = "med" , cmap = "jet", data=df)
fig.colorbar(sc, label="med")
ax.set(xlabel="longitude", ylabel="latitude")

plt.show()
```

Finally you may now ask whether supplying the data to matplotlib via the `data` argument would not equally be possible via passing through the pandas wrapper. Unfortunately not, because pandas uses `data` as argument internally such that it'll not be passed through.
Therefore your two options are:

1. Use pandas as in the question and supply the data itself via the `s` argument instead of the column name.
2. Use matplotlib as shown here and use column names for all arguments. (Or use the data itself, which you see most often when looking at matplotlib code.)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. One question now: How can I find out which parameters pandas converts and which parameter it doesn't?

Comment: I think the bad news is: you can't find out without looking through the source code. But in general pandas uses `x` and `y` and accepts labels for them. In the case of scatter it is `c` as well.