# In Python, what's the right way to pass a timezone to datetime.strptime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, date-parsing

I'm using Python 3.7 and none of the solutions from this post -- [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones) applied to me.  I had this for generating a datetime from text ...

```
datetime.strptime(created_on_txt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

This later results in the warning ...

```
DateTimeField Article.created_on received a naive datetime (2019-12-09 00:08:17.670597) while time zone support is active.
```

So I added a timezone like so ...

```
datetime(pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)).strptime(created_on_txt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

But this results in the error ...

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What's the right way to get the timezone into the datetime?

Comment: if you don't mind using pandas, its to_datetime method is pretty flexible `pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01T01:01:01 EST')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas.plot argument c vs s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412449/pandas-plot-argument-c-vs-s)

Comment: @Marat, if I already have the date as a string (e.g. "2017-01-01T01:01:01"), without the timezone, how do I create a datetime object given that I know the timezone as a separate string (e.g. America/New York)?

Comment: @Dave just append the timezone (EST for NY) to the end of the string: `pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01T01:01:01' + ' EST)`